# Install Network Adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

My onboard ethernet adapter fried on a thunderstorm, I just bought a network adpater (Intelbras Pef 132), but it is not working,it doesn't connect, it says to run on Linux systems, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, the drive it came is "8139too.c" and a makefile. I tried to run the `make` but it says

```
gcc -O6 -Wall -DCONFIG_KERNELD -DMODULE -D__KERNEL__ -DLINUX -DUSE_MEM_OPS -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-47/include/ -c 8139too.c -o 8139too.o
8139too.c:106:26: fatal error: linux/config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/config.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated
```

i changed the `NEW_INCLUDE_PATH` variable in the make path to `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-56/include/` to match my current kernel, but it still gave me the same error.

the command `ifconfig -a`

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:3f:af:f7:b7  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:3f:af:f7:b7  
          inet addr:169.254.11.21  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2420 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2420 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:223888 (223.8 KB)  TX bytes:223888 (223.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:de:27:09:33:ba  
          inet addr:192.168.0.13  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::eade:27ff:fe09:33ba/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:79163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:47850 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:111213209 (111.2 MB)  TX bytes:4969674 (4.9 MB)
```

`wlan0` is the one I'm using right now (my brothers wifi adapter), `eht1` is the adapter I bought.

```
#dmesg | grep -e eth -e 8139

[    0.277199] pci 0000:05:02.0: [10ec:8139] type 00 class 0x020000
[    1.349651] 8139cp: 8139cp: 10/100 PCI Ethernet driver v1.3 (Mar 22, 2004)
[    1.349657] 8139cp 0000:05:02.0: This (id 10ec:8139 rev 10) is not an 8139C+ compatible chip, use 8139too
[    1.351813] 8139too: 8139too Fast Ethernet driver 0.9.28
[    1.352563] 8139too 0000:05:02.0 eth0: RealTek RTL8139 at 0x000000000001e800, 00:1a:3f:af:f7:b7, IRQ 17
[   11.861547] 8139too 0000:05:02.0 eth1: renamed from eth0
[   11.871537] systemd-udevd[348]: renamed network interface eth0 to eth1
[   18.202933] 8139too 0000:05:02.0 eth1: link down
[   18.202986] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[ 3290.204357] 8139too 0000:05:02.0 eth1: link down
[ 3290.204434] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[ 4845.027723] 8139too 0000:05:02.0 eth1: link down
[ 4845.027843] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[ 5989.527102] 8139too: 8139too Fast Ethernet driver 0.9.28
[ 5989.528048] 8139too 0000:05:02.0 eth0: RealTek RTL8139 at 0x000000000001e800, 00:1a:3f:af:f7:b7, IRQ 17
[ 5989.529618] 8139too 0000:05:02.0 eth1: renamed from eth0
[ 5989.545796] systemd-udevd[18359]: renamed network interface eth0 to eth1
[ 5989.548202] 8139too 0000:05:02.0 eth1: link down
[ 5989.548283] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[ 6076.132252] 8139too: 8139too Fast Ethernet driver 0.9.28
[ 6076.133132] 8139too 0000:05:02.0 eth0: RealTek RTL8139 at 0x000000000001e800, 00:1a:3f:af:f7:b7, IRQ 17
[ 6076.133622] 8139too 0000:05:02.0 eth1: renamed from eth0
[ 6076.147222] systemd-udevd[18408]: renamed network interface eth0 to eth1
[ 6076.149372] 8139too 0000:05:02.0 eth1: link down
[ 6076.149451] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
```

I add the last two lines to`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

The file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` contains two rules for the ethernet, eth0 I think is the one which fried.

```
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="48:5b:39:f9:34:bb", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8139 (8139too)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:1a:3f:af:f7:b7", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

I tried commenting out the r8169, but it doesn't do anything.

So, whats wrong with this adapter? Why it doesn't connect? How do I install it properly?

## EDIT

`cat /var/log/syslog | grep eth1` returns

```
Apr  1 19:58:25 fernando-PC avahi-autoipd(eth1)[2588]: Found user 'avahi-autoipd' (UID 105) and group 'avahi-autoipd' (GID 113).
Apr  1 19:58:25 fernando-PC avahi-autoipd(eth1)[2588]: Successfully called chroot().
Apr  1 19:58:25 fernando-PC avahi-autoipd(eth1)[2588]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Apr  1 19:58:25 fernando-PC avahi-autoipd(eth1)[2588]: Starting with address 169.254.11.21
Apr  1 19:58:31 fernando-PC avahi-autoipd(eth1)[2588]: Callout BIND, address 169.254.11.21 on interface eth1
Apr  1 19:58:31 fernando-PC avahi-daemon[692]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv4 with address 169.254.11.21.
Apr  1 19:58:31 fernando-PC avahi-daemon[692]: New relevant interface eth1.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr  1 19:58:31 fernando-PC avahi-daemon[692]: Registering new address record for 169.254.11.21 on eth1.IPv4.
Apr  1 19:58:35 fernando-PC avahi-autoipd(eth1)[2588]: Successfully claimed IP address 169.254.11.21
Apr  1 19:58:35 fernando-PC NetworkManager[2731]:    SCPluginIfupdown: guessed connection type (eth1) = 802-3-ethernet
Apr  1 19:58:35 fernando-PC NetworkManager[2731]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: update_connection_setting_from_if_block: name:eth1, type:802-3-ethernet, id:Ifupdown (eth1), uuid: 7b635ed6-2640-7ad8-675d-744db12dd9fa
Apr  1 19:58:35 fernando-PC NetworkManager[2731]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: adding eth1 to connections
Apr  1 19:58:35 fernando-PC NetworkManager[2731]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: adding iface eth1 to eni_ifaces
Apr  1 19:58:35 fernando-PC NetworkManager[2731]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:05:02.0/net/eth1, iface: eth1)
Apr  1 19:58:35 fernando-PC NetworkManager[2731]: <info> (eth1): carrier is OFF
Apr  1 19:58:35 fernando-PC NetworkManager[2731]: <info> (eth1): new Ethernet device (driver: '8139too' ifindex: 2)
Apr  1 19:58:35 fernando-PC NetworkManager[2731]: <info> (eth1): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1
Apr  1 20:05:23 fernando-PC dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x51da0147)
.
.
.
Apr  1 20:38:38 fernando-PC dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xabe24e5a)
```

Comment: It looks like the compile failed, you will probably not get anywhere till you fix that problem.  Do you have `build-essential` installed?  (I am just guessing, the few times I've had to compile something, I needed that).

Comment: "build-essential is already the newest version."

Comment: It appears that the driver 8139 already comes with linux. I wondering what this line means `This (id 10ec:8139 rev 10) is not an 8139C+ compatible chip, use 8139too`

Comment: As you can see by your `dmesg`, 8139too is already included, loaded and creates an interface; namely eth1. Your problem is not the driver. The line you've quoted is common and may safely be ignored.

Comment: Okay, so if the driver is inclued and loaded, what else can it be then?

Comment: You haven't said what is wrong yet. Does it try but fail to connect? Does it connect but drop? Is it slow? Or...what? Are there any clues in the log? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep eth1`

Comment: It doesn't connect at all. Updated the question with the log. It seems that Carrier is OFF. No clue what it means.

Answer (score 0):

I feel really angry, relieved and stupid right now.

The problem was that the thunder fried the router port too.

After spending around 5 hours I tried to install board and driver on Windows, which didn't work either, and the 'help' menu said the cable was not connected, I tried to change cable and port... Voila.

Moral of the story, always double check cable, ports and modem/router. If it's not software/drive problem, it must be hardware!

Thanks everyone who commented.